# How can I stop a react-query useQuery running on a refetchInterval when a condition is met?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a requirement to keep fetching data until a condition is met
I can set up the fetch on an interval with the snippet below but I can't figure out how to stop the `fetchData` when needed. Is this possible?

```
const { status: answersStatus, data: answers } = useQuery(
                           ['fetchData', { context, activity, stage, country }], 
                           fetchData,
                           {refetchInterval: 2000});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**update**:

since react-query [v3.25.0](https://github.com/TanStack/query/releases/tag/v3.25.0), `refetchInterval` can accept a function to accommodate this use-case better:

```
refetchInterval: data => (isConditionMet(data) ? false : 2000)
```

**original answer**:

with a local state:

```
const [refetchInterval, setRefetchInterval] = React.useState(2000)
const { status: answersStatus, data: answers } = useQuery(
    ['fetchData', { context, activity, stage, country }], 
    fetchData,
    {refetchInterval});
```

you can set the `refetchInterval` to `false` or `0` to turn it off. If you want to do it depending on the response, the `onSuccess`, `onError` or `onSettled` callbacks are likely the best place:

```
const [refetchInterval, setRefetchInterval] = React.useState(2000)
const { status: answersStatus, data: answers } = useQuery(
    ['fetchData', { context, activity, stage, country }], 
    fetchData,
    {
        refetchInterval,
        onError: () => setRefetchInterval(0)
    });
```

Comment: I prefer the use of the `refetchInterval: data => (checkMyResponseHere(data) ? false : 2000)` function because it doesn't require state

Comment: you're right - I've written this answer before I added the refetchInterval-as-a-function feature. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was causing infinite loop until passing function to the `refetchInterval` like so:

`refetchInterval: data => (checkMyResponseHere(data) ? false : 2000)`

P.S. react-query v.3.38.0

Comment: This works! thanks dude. 

Funny this doesn't show up in the React Query docs

Comment: it's in the api docs: `refetchInterval: number | false | ((data: TData | undefined, query: Query) => number | false)`

Answer (score 1):

In the end I leveraged `short-circuit evaluation` so my call is now

```js
const { data: answers } = useQuery(
    isThereSomethingToGet && [`fetchData`, { ...qmfRouteParams, context: appContext }],
    fetchData,
    {
      refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
      refetchInterval: DocusignPolling.INTERVAL,
    },
  );
```

When `isThereSomethingToGet` is falsy the function isn't called.

Comment: react-query is not stopping the execution of the queryFn due to falsy query keys (not on v3 at least). to disable a query, you need to set the `enabled` boolean to `false`.

Comment: @TkDodo Is there a way to prevent fetching when `refetch` method get called?

Answer (score 1):

As of Tanstack Query v5, the signature has changed from

```
refetchInterval: number | false | ((data: TData | undefined, query: Query) => number | false)
```

to

```
refetchInterval: number | false | ((query: Query) => number | false | undefined)
```

So instead of doing

```
refetchInterval: data => (isConditionMet(data) ? false : 2000)
```

like in [TkDodo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265302/5706830), you'll need to do:

```
refetchInterval: query => (isConditionMet(query.state.data) ? false : 2000)
```

Comment: thank you for putting the effort of mentioning this here!

Answer (score 0):

With React Query v4, you need to pass the 'refetchInterval' like below:

```js
useQuery({ queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: ()=>{}, refetchInterval: (data)=> data.refetchNeeded? 5000: false })
```

Here, refetchNeeded is the boolean field from the previously fetched data.